# Mysql varchar as int max value

Tags: mysql, compare, varchar

A query is needed that returns the `maximal or minimum` value of `VARCHAR`. Compares as `unsigned int`, a value not int does not simply take into account.

For example,

```
1
2
3
gggg123
435
500000.123
```

Answer: `maximum - 435, minimum - 1`

```
NULL
fff
1
- 56
```

Answer: `maximum - 1, minimum - 1`

Comment: Thus - you need to compare only values which are valid integers?

Comment: Why `maximum - 1, minimum - 1`?

Comment: [*fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b90fa/5)

Answer (score 1):

Since you require only positive integer you need to extract column values using regular expression which are positive number and then find Max from them

```
Select MAX(Cast(columnName) as UNSIGNED)
From tableName
Where columnName REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

**EDIT**

As pointed by Alma Do, CAST to INT doesn't exist in Mysql , instead its equivalent is UNSIGNED.

Anyways casting not required here ..

```
    Select MAX(columnName),MIN(columnName)
    From tableName
    Where columnName REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Again, fail (CAST is _wrong_ here). Also - `CAST` to `INT` _doesn't exist_

Comment: @AlmaDo but WHERE condition will filter out these values due to regular expression ...